# Is it possible to assign a "custom group" to a specific roles of users?

Tags: custom-fields, permissions

I have a custom set of data that I wøuld like be only visible to users with specific permission.  is it possible to achieve? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use 'Access Control Lists'. You can access it by 'Administer->Users and Permissions'. Then go to 'Manage ACLs' to and define a ACL for a Custom Data Set.
[image: ACL for Custom Data Set]

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks So much. But probably would be useful for some to elaborate a little more in the answer that its not a 1 step process.

Comment: Tapash - i think if you search in civi documentation it would not be hard to find, and you could then offer that link as help to others.